# Highcharts: Moving yaxis label to the top left of chart

Tags: highcharts

In the below chart is it possible to move the y axis label(africa) to the top left of the graph.

[image]

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Africa'],
    title: {
        text: null
    }
}

https://jsfiddle.net/wanp1bqg/2/
```

Output like the below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reposition the label in the `render` event, example:

```
events: {
  render: function() {
    this.xAxis[0].ticks[0].label.attr({
      y: this.plotTop
    });
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rcxg3unm/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr

Comment: thank you so much...is it possible to move straight to 0. the africa should start top left straight to 0.

Comment: Hi @Raphael, Do you mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bcef90zd/ ?

Comment: Thanks, set `labels.align` to 'left' and `labels.x` to 0, example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c309ogu4/